# Buscador con filtros para custom loop post

Tags: wordpress, buscador, función-personalizada

¡Buenas!

Estoy trabajando en una web inmobiliaria, que tiene propiedades, agentes....etc

La he creado con `ACF (Custom Post Type)` y `Elementor`, todo funciona perfecto, pero a la hora de realizar búsquedas, no encuentro nada para realizar un formulario avanzando donde se pueda buscar por filtros.

Es decir, los inmuebles tienen precio(input rango), caracteristicas(input checkbox)...etc

Y me gustaría tener un buscador con filtros como los de los tipicos temas de real estate, para que la búsqueda sea mas funcional, pero no encuentro nada.

He probado plugins tipo `Ivory-Search` o `Live-Ajax`, pero solo permiten al buscador "encontrar" custom post types.

Comment: "*Me gustaría tener un buscador con filtros como los de los típicos temas de real estate*" Es algo muy genérico y abierto como para que podamos darte una respuesta concreta ¿Por qué no nos muestras lo que tienes hecho para que podamos tomarlo como punto de partida?

Comment: una opción es interceptar el action `pre_get_posts` ver si el `$wp_query` es un search y modificar el query con el filter `post_where` para ponerle un between los dos rangos, luego limpias el filter en el action `posts_selection` para que no afecte otras consultas